# asp.net core 3.1 EF ConcurrencyCheck not working using razor CRUD scaffolding not MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am new to ConcurrencyCheck I started a new blank asp.net core VStudio project, and i'm using just Razor pages and CRUD razor scaffolding. When i try and make a change with Model Class properties set with [ConcurrencyCheck] i get a DbUpdateConcurrencyException even though i'm the only one person accessing my test setup and dbase in debug mode. am I not understanding how ConcurrencyCheck is supposed to work ? I assumed it should not hit any sort of exception.

here is my code.. it's all vanilla/blank VStudio project and just default stuff other than my context and model class files below.

my context

```
 public class AppDbContext :DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
         : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<CustInfo> cust_info { get; set; }
    }
```

my model

```
public class CustInfo
    {
        [Key]
        public int request_id { get; set; }

        [ConcurrencyCheck]
        public string customer_name { get; set; }

        [ConcurrencyCheck]
        public string customer_phone { get; set; }

        [ConcurrencyCheck]
        public string customer_email { get; set; }
    }
```

my Edit razor page .cs

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly TestApp.Classes.AppDbContext _context;

        public EditModel(TestApp.Classes.AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public CustInfo CustInfo { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            CustInfo = await _context.cust_info.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.request_id == id);

            if (CustInfo == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Page();
        }

        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.Attach(CustInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!CustInfoExists(CustInfo.request_id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

        private bool CustInfoExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.cust_info.Any(e => e.request_id == id);
        }
    }
```

When i am on the edit page and change say the email address of a customer , then click save button, if have a breakpoint set on the "await _context.SaveChangesAsync();" line , it hits the following exception

{"Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."}

i would expect there to NOT be any exceptions so can't figure out why this is not working. i would think the save to dbase would work because i'm the only one changing anything debugging this project.  If i remove the [ConcurrencyCheck] from customer_name, customer_phone, and customer_email in the model class and then change anyone of them no exception occurs. Just trying to figure this stuff out so i can test debugging this project with breakpoints and then change a value in the database from sql side and see an actual concurrency issue happen :) but i can't even get it to work even when i'm NOT changing anything behind the scenes in the database.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you doing `_context.Attach(CustInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;` there's no information on what is the actual state of your entity in the database. You have to fetch your entity from database, change it and then save changes.
2. I'd recommend you to remove all `ConcurrencyCheck` attributes from `CustInfo` class and add another property of type `byte[]` annotated with `TimestampAttribute` that will play the role of concurrency token. EF generates its value automatically on insert or update and check if its value has changed by someone else during update operation to prevent concurrent access.

Comment: i saw that method, so if i use the timestamp then i don't need the [ConcurrencyCheck] attributes OK gotcha.

Comment: I don't have concurrency on my model class and I am getting the same error in a development environment

Comment: @Nicolas I suppose you have to create another question and provide more data on your case